# I just wrote some code for a simple game, but my try-except code keeps messing up

Tags: python

I have a try-except statement in a loop:

```
while alive_tanks > 1:
  for tank_name in sorted(tanks.keys()):
    print(tank_name,tanks[tank_name])
  first = input('Who fires?\n').lower
  second = input('At who?\n').lower
  
  try:
    first_tank = tanks[first]
    second_tank = tanks[second]
  except KeyError:
    print('Please input the name of a tank!')
    continue
```

But my try-except doesn't work even if I input a correct name of a tank.

Comment: Right now in your code `first` and `second` aren't two strings. You can verify that by printing them. You need to change it to `first = input('Who fires?\n').lower()`. Same for `second`.

Comment: Can you edit your post to explain what "doesn't work" means exactly? Do you get an error? Does the code run partially? What output do you get?

Comment: `lower` is a function, so you must call it like `lower()`, otherwise instead of string a function object will be returned. The dictionary keys are string, so it will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the fixed code:

```
while alive_tanks > 1:
   for tank_name in sorted(tanks.keys()):
       print(tank_name,tanks[tank_name])
       first = input('Who fires?\n').lower()
       second = input('At who?\n').lower()
  
       try:
           first_tank = tanks[first]
           second_tank = tanks[second]
       except KeyError:
           print('Please input the name of a tank!')
           continue
```